Python Importing from different directories
I have the following folder setup
user_test.py
factories/
    user_factory.py
pb/
    user_pb2.py
    user_pb2_grpc.py

This is how the imports are in each of the files
user_test.py
    import factories.user_factory

factories/user_factory.py
    import pb.user_pb2_grpc

pb/user_pb2_grpc.py
    import user_pb2

However, on the last line I get an error saying
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'user_pb2'
pb/user_pb2_grpc.py is not being able to import user_pb2.py even though they are in the same directory
This can be fixed by changing import user_pb2 to from . import user_pb2 but this is Autgenerated code by GRPC and I cannot change.
Any help on how to resolve this error or better structure my code?
